# Make WebStorm recognize method defined in jest.setupFilesAfterEnv

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, webstorm, code-hinting

In Webstorm, I'm using jest for unit tests, and have created an extension using `expect.extend()`. The code for this is in `{projectDir}./tests/jest-helpers.js` and in my `package.json` I have the following:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./tests/jest-helpers.js"]
}
```

This is working great, and the `expect` extension is working great in my unit tests. However, the code calling this method in my unit tests is not being recognized as valid, with a warning hint "Unresolved function or method."

I added the .js file as a Library, but this still didn't do the job. How do I get the method to be recognized? Is there some JSDoc thing I can do that will tell WebStorm that the `expect` object has a new property?

Example of my `expect` extension definition that isn't being picked up as a valid method.

```
// jest-helper.js
expect.extend({
   toSmellLike(actual, expected) {
      // an implementation
   }
});
```

In use:

```
expect(value).toSmellLike('bananas'); // `toSmellLike is highlighted with a warning
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same....the best I got was to use JSDoc comment to get custom method highlighted.

```
/**
 * @typedef {jest.Expect} expect
 * @property {function} toSmellLike
 */
```

Just add this above your extend call and it should work.

Still looking how to get code completion working with it.